# Custom Data Attribute not Populating Value

Tags: php, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a simple delete function. Here is where I set the custom data:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
              __('Delete'),
              '#CoursesModal',
              array(
                'class' => 'btn-remove-modal',
                'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                'role'  => 'button',
                'data-uid' => $course['Course']['id'],
                'data-uname' => $course['Course']['name']
              ));
            ?>
```

It shows in the element fine:

```
<a href="#CoursesModal" class="btn-remove-modal" data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-uid="5" data-uname="Advanced Environmental Catastrophies">Delete</a>
```

But when it comes to deleting this object (here's the code for it:)

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete'),'/courses/delete/#{uid}',array('class' => 'btn btn-danger delete-course-link')) ?>
```

For some reason the {uid} doesn't translate to 5 - which causes it not to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wrap the link in double quotes instead on singles, i know that affects php variables but i don't know about this...

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't the answer. The {uid} is in a modal box which should be populated with the appropriate uid from the data-uid in the Delete link. So somewhere there is the disconnect. I am wondering if I'm missing a plugin or something?

Comment: Can you output the contents of {uid} on its own?

Comment: It works only on the initial page load (on elements that are loaded initially) but on the modal which is supposed to populate with the id of the object I'm selecting - it just shows {uid}.

I circumvented the issue by just putting the actual URL path that would run the delete function but it was a quick and dirty solution. Solved the issue but I'd rather do it the right way.